# Сортировка записей на основе значения поля по очереди

Tags: sql, oracle

Предположим есть 10 записей в одном из полей у которых, у 5 записей значение 1, а у других 5 записей значение 2. Как можно так отсортировать, что бы эти записи пошли по очереди, 1, 2, 1, 2..., А если какие то из значений закончатся, то есть останутся записи только с одним из этих значений, что бы они уже по порядку просто пошли. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT subquery.[fieldset]
FROM (SELECT table.[fieldset]
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table.data_field 
                                ORDER BY table.some_unique_field) rn
      FROM table
     ) subquery
ORDER BY subquery.rn ASC, subquery.data_field ASC
```

Comment: P.S. Запрос проверен на https://livesql.oracle.com/.